# PyFladesk Migration

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, flask, pyqt

I wanted to contribute to the [PyFladesk](https://github.com/smoqadam/PyFladesk) project. The objective is to have a function that receives a Flask's app and embeds it in a Qt desktop app.

I've already [create a Pull Request](https://github.com/smoqadam/PyFladesk/pull/4) on the main repository, individual commmits and changes can be viewed there

This was the initial version: 83 lines - 3 Classes - 1 Function - Uses PyQt4

> ```
> import sys,webbrowser
>
> from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, QUrl,SIGNAL,QSize
> from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication,QMainWindow,QIcon
> from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView,QWebPage
>
> # CONFIG
> PORT = 5000
> ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:{}'.format(PORT)
> WIDTH = 300
> HEIGHT = 400
> WINDOW_TITLE = "PyFladesk"
> ICON = 'appicon.png'
>
>
> # run flask on seperate theared
> class FlaskThread(QThread):
>     def __init__(self, application):
>         QThread.__init__(self)
>         self.application = application
>
>     def __del__(self):
>         self.wait()
>
>     def run(self):
>         self.application.run(port=PORT)
>
>
> class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         QMainWindow.__init__(self)
>         self.resize (WIDTH , HEIGHT)
>         self.setWindowTitle(WINDOW_TITLE)
>         self.webView = WebView(self)
>         self.setCentralWidget(self.webView)
>
>
>
> class WebView(QWebView):
>     def __init__(self ,parent=None):
>         super(WebView,self).__init__(parent)
>
>     def dragEnterEvent(self,e):
>         e.ignore()
>
>     def dropEvent(self,e):
>         e.ignore()
>
>     def contextMenuEvent(self,e):
>         pass
>
>     # open links in default browser 
>     # stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3188942/1103397 :D
>     def linkClicked(self,url): 
>         webbrowser.open(url.toEncoded().data())
>
>
> def provide_GUI_for(application):
>     qtapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
>
>     webapp = FlaskThread(application)
>     webapp.start()
>
>     qtapp.aboutToQuit.connect(webapp.terminate)
>
>     mainWindow = MainWindow()
>     # set app icon    
>     mainWindow.setWindowIcon(QIcon(ICON))
>
>     # prevent open urls in QWebView.
>     mainWindow.webView.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
>     mainWindow.webView.connect(mainWindow.webView, SIGNAL("linkClicked (const QUrl&)"), mainWindow.webView.linkClicked)
>
>     mainWindow.webView.load(QUrl(ROOT_URL))
>     mainWindow.show()
>
>     return qtapp.exec_()
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     from routes import app
>     provide_GUI_for(app)
> ```

And this is the updated version: 50 lines - 1 Function - Uses PyQt 5.10.0

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets


def init_gui(application, port=5000, width=300, height=400,
            window_title="PyFladesk", icon="appicon.png"):

    ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:{}'.format(port)

    # open links in browser from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3188942/1103397 :D
    # thanks to https://github.com/marczellm/qhangups/blob/cfed73ee4383caed1568c0183a9906180f01cb00/qhangups/WebEnginePage.py
    def link_clicked(url, typ, ismainframe):
        ready_url = url.toEncoded().data().decode()
        is_clicked = typ == QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked
        is_not_internal = ROOT_URL not in ready_url
        if is_clicked and is_not_internal:
            QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
            return False
        return True

    def run_app():
        application.run(port=port, threaded=True)

    # Application Level
    qtapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webapp = QtCore.QThread()
    webapp.__del__ = webapp.wait
    webapp.run = run_app
    webapp.start()
    qtapp.aboutToQuit.connect(webapp.terminate)

    # Main Window Level
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.resize(width, height)
    window.setWindowTitle(window_title)
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon))

    # WebView Level
    window.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(window)
    window.setCentralWidget(window.webView)

    # WebPage Level
    page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage()
    page.acceptNavigationRequest = link_clicked
    page.load(QtCore.QUrl(ROOT_URL))
    window.webView.setPage(page)

    window.show()

    return qtapp.exec_()
```

Some of my concerns are:

- Is it a good decision not to use classes at all?
- Is the code readable and maintainable?
- Are there any suggestions to improve it?

This was once review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114221/84718)

Comment: [Original review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114221/84718) of PyFladesk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not too found of putting it all into a single method as:

1. it seems to have too much responsibilities;
2. building some objects (`QThread`, `QWebEnginePage`) is really awkward when methods are reassigned.

I really like using default values for parameters instead of global constants, though.

Instead I’d go with an intermediate state where I’d use proper subclassing instead of methods assignment:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets


class ApplicationThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, application, port=5000):
        super(ApplicationThread, self).__init__()
        self.application = application
        self.port = port

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        self.application.run(port=self.port, threaded=True)


class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, root_url):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.root_url = root_url

    def home(self):
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.root_url))

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, kind, is_main_frame):
        """open external links in browser and internal links in the regular webview"""
        # thanks to https://github.com/marczellm/qhangups/blob/cfed73ee4383caed1568c0183a9906180f01cb00/qhangups/WebEnginePage.py
        ready_url = url.toEncoded().data().decode()
        is_clicked = kind == self.NavigationTypeLinkClicked
        if is_clicked and self.root_url not in ready_url:
            QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(url)
            return False
        return super(WebPage, self).acceptNavigationRequest(url, kind, is_main_frame)


def init_gui(application, port=5000, width=300, height=400,
             window_title="PyFladesk", icon="appicon.png", argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    # Application Level
    qtapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(argv)
    webapp = ApplicationThread(application, port)
    webapp.start()
    qtapp.aboutToQuit.connect(webapp.terminate)

    # Main Window Level
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.resize(width, height)
    window.setWindowTitle(window_title)
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon))

    # WebView Level
    webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(window)
    window.setCentralWidget(webView)

    # WebPage Level
    page = WebPage('http://localhost:{}'.format(port))
    page.home()
    webView.setPage(page)

    window.show()
    return qtapp.exec_()
```

Back to two classes and a few more lines, but subclassing really feels better here. I also removed assigning the web-view as a `window` attribute as I don't see the need.

Lastly, I added support for user-provided `argv` (for testing purposes), just in case; not sure if really needed.

Comment: My question is, is it worth it to declare a class just to redefine 3 methods, all of them magic methods (ApplicationThread)?

Comment: I look at it the other way around. Is it worth it to cram everything into a god method only for the sake of removing classes? To me, the ugly part is how you reassign methods; when subclassing and overriding are way more natural (and I didn't have to invent anything, just reuse the functions you were already using).

Comment: You are right, maybe I'm trying too hard to avoid OOP in Python but it seems like it's the Qt style to subclass and redefine methods.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, there are times when I think [OOP is the wrong tool for the job](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/187505/84718). But yes, this is Qt, everything is classes already.